# can't run build when productionGzip is true (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When i change in index.js the value of productionGzip to true ,i have this problem when i build the project with : npm run build :

> vue-pwa@1.0.0 build /home/anas/Bureau/VueJS/vue-pwa
>   node build/build.js

/home/anas/Bureau/VueJS/vue-pwa/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:32
    throw new ValidationError(ajv.errors, name);
    ^

ValidationError: Compression Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties

```
at validateOptions (/home/anas/Bureau/VueJS/vue-pwa/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/src/validateOptions.js:32:11)
at new CompressionPlugin (/home/anas/Bureau/VueJS/vue-pwa/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:55:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anas/Bureau/VueJS/vue-pwa/build/webpack.prod.conf.js:116:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anas/Bureau/VueJS/vue-pwa/build/build.js:13:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-pwa@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-pwa@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anas/.npm/_logs/2018-09-21T13_08_37_566Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed this by downgrading the *compression-webpack-plugin* in my package.json devDependencies to 1.1.11.
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5PiQ.png)

Comment: Did you 'npm install' after changing the package version? You have to do so before 'npm run build'.
Try the following steps:
1. npm install compression_webpack-plugin@1.1.11
2. npm install
3. npm run build

Answer (score 1):

the config key named "asset" was changed to "filename"